# How to convert MM/dd/yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd format ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I have a Gridview in my aspx page that displays Names and Dates coming from my Database and some Textbox to search data from Database.

The format of the dates saved in my database is **yyyy-MM-dd** but I want to display it on my Gridview in **MM/dd/yyyy**, so I used

```
SELECT ID, Name, convert(varchar(10), StartDate, 101) as [StartDate] FROM MyDB
```

to make it happen. Now instead of displaying **2016-12-13**, it is displayed on my gridview like this: **12/13/2016**

Now my problem is, when I'm using my textbox to filter the Gridview using the dates, the format of the date typed should be in **yyyy-MM-dd** in order for it to display results. That's why I'm thinking of converting the **MM/dd/yyyy** typed in the textbox to **yyyy-MM-dd**.

So when I type **12/13/2016**, It will be converted to **2016-12-13** then add it to my SQLCommand.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention the reason why I'm converting the date. That's because it also displays Time in the Gridview even though the data saved in Database is date only. So without converting, it looks like this: **5/12/2016 12:00:00 AM**

Comment: Are you dealing with `string` or `DateTime`?

Comment: What type is the `StartDate` column in your database?

Comment: If you retrieve the value as DateTime from database and display it, it will automatically adjust to the current selected locale your are on. Furthermore if you get a valid DateTime from the Model, you do not need to worry when using Entity Framework or SqlCommand AddParameter. So I would suggest to go the 'DateTime' way - cause every different web local display could lead to a problem.

Comment: I think it will be better to get the datetime as it is stored in DB and only convert this while displaying. That way you have flexibility for representation.

Comment: use this in your GridView Binding on aspx page.  Text='<%#Eval("Date", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. They don't have any format in the database or .NET. If you store dates as text in the database, you have a serious database design bug. Change the `StartDate` field's type to `date` and remove the conversion entirely

Comment: ASP.NET will format dates for display based on the *end user's* language selection. You can override this by configuring the culture at the page, web app or thread level. No manual formatting is necessary

Comment: StartDate is 'date' type @phuzi

Comment: @PauGacusan then you don't have to do anything apart from **removing** `convert(varchar(10), StartDate, 101)` completely and simply return `StartDate`. If you want to display the date using the ISO format in your grid, set the column's format property

Comment: @PauGacusan then you don't need to format it until .Net, it's a date and doesn't have a format.

Comment: @Fildor I don't exactly know what to answer. The texts typed on textbox are strings right? So I think it will be a conversion from string to Date since my 'StartDate' is 'date' after all

Comment: @PauGacusan dates are dates, not strings. Post your *gridview* code. `BoundField` for example has a `DataFormatString` property that you can set to `"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` if you want. Far better to set the correct culture though, or let the browser decide

Comment: @PauGacusan again `date` has *no* format. `YYYY-MM-DD` is the format used by SSMS to display dates.

Comment: @GaurangDave I did that but it displays time which is not needed to be displayed

Comment: @PauGacusan read the duplicate. And [GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Formatting the GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx). If you want help with formatting your gridview column, post your code. Did you *set* the format string for the column? You can use a short format, eg `d` to specify that only a date will be displayed in the end-user's locale

Comment: Ok, So your db result has DateTime and you get a string from a TextBox. Would it be an option to replace the textbox with a DatePicker?

Comment: @PauGacusan please try this one as well :   text='<%# Eval("DateAdded", "{0:d}") %>'

Comment: @GaurangDave time is still displayed along with the date. I think I'll need to format the gridview like PanagiotisKanavos said if I'm going to bind my gridview like this. Since it looks like this is the proper approach. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the references. I'll be able to use this to improve the development of my web since it contains a lot of GridView. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(
    DateTime.ParseExact("12/13/2016","d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

produces `2016-12-13`

Comment: Better yet, don't convert the date to text at all when querying so no conversion will be necessary

Comment: As the OP mentioned, `StartDate` is a `date` field. GridView columns have a `DataFormatString` property No need for conversions or parsing at all.

Comment: @PhillipNgan Thank you sir. It worked.